# How to add physics to the transformation of generalised coordinates

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, velocity, coordinate-systems

I've been introduced to the conversion between generalized coordinates, where $x_j = f(q_1,q_2,q_3,t_q)$ a scalar function where we are converting from $(q_1,q_2,q_3,t_q)$ to $(x_1,x_2,x_3,t_x)$.

Because $q_1,q_2,q_3$ can be written as functions of $t_q$ we have the derivative

$$\dot{\mathbf{x}}_{j}=\sum_{k}\frac{\partial\mathbf{x}_{j}}{\partial q_{k}}\dot{q}_k+\frac{\partial\mathbf{x}_{j}}{\partial t_q}$$

for $k,j$ ranging from $1$ to $3$. There is a similar equation for $t_x$.

There are a couple of things which confuse me. First of all, so far, other than the limits on the number of coordinates there is nothing physical about these equations. The coordinates are essentially supposed to describe position and time but at the moment they describe arbitrary functions of four variables. For example, at this point it seems that $\frac{\partial\mathbf{x}_{j}}{\partial t_q}$ could well be a non zero term. In real life a change in position in one coordinate system *must* follow a change in position in another, but this final term implies that $x$ can change independent of the position in the other coordinate system. The only counterexample I can find is the galilean transformation.

Another example of physics is that time between coordinate systems can only be shifted by a constant. This will have its own implications.

So I'm trying to justify all these intuitions by introducing laws of physics into this equation. what is the physical significance of the final term $\frac{\partial\mathbf{x}_{j}}{\partial t_q}$? If it is usually zero, then what is the physical reason for this, and if not, where does it come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In real life a change in position in one coordinate system must follow a change in position in another [...]

Your view of what constitutes a change in coordinates is too limited, I think.  Consider the case of a bead which slides along a frictionless circular hoop of radius $R$, which is being rotated at a constant angular velocity $\omega$.  The position of the bead can be described by specifying the coordinates $x(t),y(t)$, and $z(t)$, but such coordinates would be subject to a very irritating constraint.

Instead, the position could be specified by the angle the bead makes from the vertical ($\theta=0$ denoting the bottom of the hoop, $\theta=\pi$ denoting the top) and the azimuthal angle $\phi$ which is changing with time ($\dot \phi = \omega$).  Furthermore, because $\omega$ is constant, we are perfectly entitled to switch to the variable $\psi = \phi - \omega t$ which is constant in time ($\dot \psi = 0$).

It should be clear that a bead with a constant $\theta$ and $\psi$-coordinates will generically correspond to non-constant $x$ and $y$-coordinates.  In some sense, this is the entire point of changing to a generalized coordinate system.

---

To be explicit, given $x,y,$ and $z$ (Cartesian coordinates), we can switch to our $\theta,\psi$ coordinates as follows:

$$x = R\sin(\theta)\cos(\psi+\omega t)$$
$$y = R\sin(\theta)\sin(\psi+\omega t)$$
$$z = R(1-\cos(\theta))$$
and
$$\theta = \cos^{-1} \left(1-\frac{z}{R}\right)$$
$$\psi = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)-\omega t$$

As you can see, we can let $\theta$ and $\psi$ be constants (where $\theta \neq 0$) and still have $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ which change with time.  In general, this situation arises whenever we introduce generalized coordinates with explicit time dependence.

---

To address the overall theme of the question, the physics is not present in the form of the coordinates themselves, but rather in the equations which govern their evolution in time.  Coordinate changes may or may not introduce explicit time dependence to the Lagrangian, but the underlying time evolution of the system will be governed by the Lagrangian equations of motion, which is where the physics actually resides.

Comment: how can the variables be constant when they depend on time?

Comment: @lucky-guess Consider the simple case of a particle moving in one direction with constant velocity $v$.  Define $f(x,t)=x-vt$. The total derivative of $f$ with respect to time is $\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \dot x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \dot x - v = v - v = 0$, so the value of $f$ is constant despite possessing explicit time dependence.

Comment: right but is there a specific example where dq/dt is 0 but the partial of x with respect to time is non zero?

Comment: @lucky-guess That's exactly what I just wrote.  $\frac{df}{dt}=0$ but $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = -v$.

Comment: @lucky-guess In the example given in my answer, $\frac{d\psi}{dt} = 0$ but $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}=-\omega$.

Comment: @lucky-guess Consider the 2D projectile problem.  Normally you use coordinates $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ - now change coordinates to $X(x,t)=x-v_{x0}t$ and $Y(y,t)=y-v_{y0}t + \frac{1}{2}gt^2$.  Both $X$ and $Y$ are constants of the motion $(\frac{dX}{dt} = \frac{dY}{dt} = 0)$ but neither of the partial derivatives with respect to time are zero.

Comment: ah i see. I was inadvertently doing exactly what i had suggested. I was limiting it to transformations that keep all accelerating objects as having non zero velocity. Or in other words, a still object is still in some inertial frame even under the transformation. But to think of it that way, it's an arbitrary place to draw the line. For example, i was not limiting it (my imagination) to transformations which keep all accelerating objects as accelerating, otherwise even spherical coordinates would be ignored

Comment: the term disappears entirely when taking only coordinates that transform points in absolute space to other points in absolute space. Those are exactly the transformations that transform to inertial frames without needing the final term.

Comment: but like i said, that is an arbitrary choice. I could have just as easily limited myself to thinking about coordinates that hold the inertial reference frame without needing term 1 and 3 or terms 1,2,3 and 4. But that said, isn't it also an arbitrary choice that $t_q$ = $t_x$?

Comment: Yes, that's also arbitrary.  You could scale the time by a constant factor, add a constant to it, raise it to the third power, or anything else you want that would result in valid, invertible change of coordinates.  

Such changes are seldom useful in my experience, but you're perfectly entitled to make them.  That's why they're called *generalized coordinates*.

Comment: @lucky-guess To be slightly more accurate, the "time" variable is the parameter which governs the evolution of the other "coordinate" variables.  Switching to a different time variable as I mentioned above simply amounts to re-parameterizing the system's path through configuration space ($q,\dot q$).  You're mathematically free to do this, but it probably won't be useful to do anything other than scaling or shifting $t$ by a constant.

Comment: it is possible to reparametrise it when the 'space' coordinates are functions of time, as in many to one. Wouldn't that be a statement of physics?

Comment: @lucky-guess I don't know what you mean by that.  As I said, the physics is contained in the assertion that the Euler Lagrange equations describe the time evolution of the system, as well as the symmetries and form of the Lagrangian.